# Detect CMS (Wordpress, etc.) based on HTML source

Tags: html, wordpress, web, content-management-system

Is there some means to identify the CMS (Content Management System) which was used for creating a webpage based on its HTML source code?

Sometimes I see webpages and immediately wonder with which tool they were developed. With tool I mean CMS like Wordpress, Drupal, Typo3, etc. I could think of some fingerprinting-technique which could do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to pinpoint the backend CMS accurately. Almost all CMS systems out there support custom themes which would have completely different HTML code.

Your best educated guess would be to try and identify the CMS by:

1. The robots.txt file in its root directory.
2. The existence of the CMS admin panel login page.
3. The folder structure used to serve page resources such as images
   and css  files.
4. The presence of a specific CMS backend file.
5. The URL structure of default services such as RSS.

For example, if you are to guess if a certain website uses WordPress, you would do the following:

1- check the existence of robots.txt and if it contains "Disallow: /wp-admin/" then there is a high chance this is a WordPress website.

2- If you get a response from accessing the default WordPress admin panel at http://domain_name/wp-admin , then there is a high chance this is a WordPress website.

3- If this file exists http://domain_name/wp-mail.php then there is a high chance this is a WordPress website.

4- If we get a valid RSS feed at this URL http://domain_name/?feed=rss2 then there is a high chance this is a WordPress website.

Now if a site meets 3 out of the 4 detection rules listed above, you can safely say it's a WordPress website.

You need to do the same thing in identifying unique detection rules for each CMS you want to detect.

Note that there are existing services such as http://whatcms.org/ and http://guess.scritch.org/ that do what I described in this answer.

Good luck!